# Составить регулярное выражение для нахождения единичного или повторяющегося символа X в тексте, обрамленном с обеих сторон символом Y

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Предположим, необходимо найти символы нижнего подчеркивания `_` в следующих строках:

```
"last_sql_error"
"wrong_type_conversion_from"
```

Решить эту задачу с помощью `positive lookbehind` достаточно просто:

```
(?<=".+)_(?=.+")
```

Однако данный оператор не поддерживается в большой части движков.
Как решить эту задачу без использования вышеуказанного оператора?

UPD:
Конкретизирую задачу.
Есть текст, в нем встречаются участки, обрамленные кавычками `"`. Символом, разделяющим слова в этих участках является не пробел, а `_`. Так вот именно в участках текста, обрамленных кавычками я хочу заменить `_` на пробел.
Пример исходного текста:

```
Я вышел на улицу и увидел на здании вывеску "магазин_продуктов", пройдя_чуть_дальше_увидел_вывеску "посторонним_вход_воспрещен"
```

Пример результирующего текста:

```
Я вышел на улицу и увидел на здании вывеску "магазин продуктов", пройдя_чуть_дальше_увидел_вывеску "посторонним вход воспрещен"
```

То есть, я хочу открыть этот текст к примеру в notepad++, найти все такие нижние подчеркивания с помощью регулярного выражения и заменить их.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, уточнить какую задачу вы решаете, чтобы стало понятно какие варианты вам могут предлагать люди. Например, вам требуется искать одиночные "_", разделяющие слова, а сами эти символы необходимо заменить на пробелы.

Comment: *>Предположим, необходимо найти символы нижнего подчеркивания `_`* — ну, для такого кейса регулярка и будет просто `_`. Сомневаюсь, что это то, чего Вы действительно хотите. Опишите задачу более подробно.

Comment: ничего не понятно, но вот https://regex101.com/r/SEB3U6/1

Comment: @МихаилМуругов суть в том, что необходимо найти символ только в участках текста обрамленных кавычками

Comment: @PotroNik уточнил вопрос, насколько понимаю ваш ответ не подходит

Comment: @StateInPrimitive обновил

Comment: Тот факт, что у вас слева и справа *одинаковый* разделитель (`"`), усложняет задачу. Попробуйте `(?:\G(?!^)|")[^\W_]*\K_(?=\w*")` ([пример](https://regex101.com/r/Jcvpl7/1))

Comment: Ну, как? Помогло? Или у вас на самом деле другой случай?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, да вот только что потестил, то что нужно, спасибо! я так понимаю это работает только на perl движке, а если используется старый ECMA, где нет lookbehind, то выхода нет... Оформите ответ, я отмечу как правильный.

Comment: Причём тут ECMAScript, если вы используете Notepad++? Или чем вы там, всё-таки, пользуетесь?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тот факт, что у вас слева и справа одинаковый разделитель (`"`), усложняет задачу.

Если принять во внимание то, что между кавычками могут находиться только букво-цифровые символы или символы нижнего подчёркивания, в Notepad++ вы можете использовать

```php
(?:\G(?!^)|")[^\W_]*\K_(?=\w*")
```

См. [пример использования регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/Jcvpl7/1). *Подробности*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|")` - конец предыдущего совпадения или символ `"`
- `[^\W_]*` - букво-цифровые символы, 0 и более повторов (кроме `_`)
- `\K` - обнуление буфера памяти текущего совпадения
- `_` - символ нижнего подчёркивания
- `(?=\w*")` - блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, требующий наличия нуля и более букво-цифровых символов или символов нижнего подчёркивания, сразу после которых идёт символ `"`.

В более общем случае, в обычных языках программирования, следует воспользоваться функцией в качестве параметра замены. Например, в JavaScript:

```js
const text = 'Тек_ст "last_sql_error" и_ "** (wrong0)_(type) | [conversion]_from" ту_т';
console.log(text.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, (x) => x.replace(/_/g, ' ')));
```